# Modify CSS for a grandchild div without a class or id

Tags: css

I'm restyling a page where I can't access the source HMTL.  Anyone know how to modify the CSS to change the background colour of the section with the word 'Notes:' as follows? I need to change the background colour,

```
<div role="region" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Message body" class="XbIp4 jmmB7 GNqVo yxtKT allowTextSelection">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Message returned to Inbox via Boomerang because there was no reply (<a href="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=XXXXX" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable" data-safelink="true" data-linkindex="0">view this conversation</a>).
                </p>            
                <div style="color:#444444;font-size:1em;background-color:#FBF1B5;width:100%;padding:0.75em;">
                    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Notes: </span>
                    <br aria-hidden="true"><br aria-hidden="true">
                    <span style="font-style:italic;">Create Order Confirmation </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com) and written this:

```
.XbIp4.jmmB7.GNqVo.yxtKT.allowTextSelection > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:#AAAAAA;
}
```

I can get the background behind the text "`Message returned to Inbox...`" to change color (from `#FFFFFF` to `#AAAAAA`) but not the background behind the text "`Notes:`" and "`Create Order Confirmation`"

Comment: try this:  .XbIp4.jmmB7.GNqVo.yxtKT.allowTextSelection div div {
  background-color:#AAAAAA;
}

Comment: @monterico this would style a div *inside* a paragraph, which doesn't exist. in your case it would be `.XbIp4.jmmB7.GNqVo.yxtKT.allowTextSelection div p + div {}` (note the **plus** between `p` + `div`

Comment: It could also be shorter, something like `.XbIp4 p + div { ... }`

Comment: Also another note, since the element itself already has a inline style `style="... background-color:#FBF1B5 ..."` you have to use `!important` in your CSS in order to override it. So .XbIp4 p + div { background-color: red !important}

Comment: do you want to have just a background color on your span where you have the word ```Notes:``` ?

Comment: Thank you both monterico and @Alex very much.  Either would have done the job nicely, but FYI the first option changed the whole background - see https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1n115spb9fqhxn and the second option (using shortened reference) changed the inner section - see https://www.dropbox.com/s/t5nqzf13qih50mt/2023-03-23_12-58-39.jpg?dl=0